# Aspell dictionaries missing when installed into nix-shell

Tags: nix, nixos

When I install the Aspell package with the Aspell dictionary for English into my global env using Nix on Mac OSX:

```
$ nix-env -iA nixpkgs.aspell nixpkgs.aspellDicts.en
```

Then Aspell behaves as I would expect:

```
$ aspell dump dicts

en
en-variant_0
...
```

However if I install the packages into a nix-shell then the Dictionary does not appear to be correctly installed:

```
$ nix-shell -p aspell aspellDicts.en --pure

$ aspell dump dicts
# nothing printed

$ echo 'word lister to check' | aspell --list
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
```

Each of the following variations produce the same problem behaviour:

- Installing into a nix-shell that is not pure,
- Putting the nix expression into a default.nix file and just running `nix-shell`.
- Installing other Aspell dictionaries

Can anyone advise how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aspell` binary is wrapped by NixPkgs, to provide the installation paths through `ASPELL_CONF` environment variable, if not already specified. (For details, `cat -v result/bin/aspell`)

You can either specify `ASPELL_CONF` manually, or use the `NIX_PROFILES` environment variable. For example:

```
$ nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {};
     buildEnv { name = "aspell-env"; paths = [aspell aspellDicts.en]; }'

$ NIX_PROFILES=./result ./result/bin/aspell dump dicts
en
en-variant_0
[...]
en_US-wo_accents
```

However, if you want to build a self-contained `aspell` install with dictionaries, you can use `aspellWithDicts`:

```
nix-build -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en])'
```

This will hardcode the `ASPELL_CONF`, so you don't need to think of those environment variables again.

Comment: Thanks Robert, Your examples work as expected ;) 
In general I'm a bit unclear on what `buildEnv` does - so any additional info would be greatly appreciated.

If I build and install a self-contained aspell (with dictionaries) using `aspellWithDicts`, this is installed as a package named `aspell-env`. Can I then use this as a `buildInput` in another package? i.e passed to `stdenv.mkDerivation`. My experiments thus far suggest not. Maybe it's because I'm not specifying the attribute path? If that is the case, how do I determine the attribute path of the installed `aspell-env`? Thanks

Comment: `buildEnv` is the function that is used under the hood by `nix-env -i` to build `~/.nix-profile`. It creates directories and symlinks to 'merge' the contents of packages together.

Comment: It should be possible to use the result of `aspellWithDicts` as a `buildInput`. There should be no need to think about where your `aspell` is installed, because typically when you are packaging something, you want to include all dependencies via the Nix expression. There is no way to reference anything that is installed during evaluation time, because that would make the expression impure. (The exception to this rule is `<nixpkgs>`, which you should try to avoid, but that's another topic)

Comment: Thanks Robert, I guess my question then is: how do I use the result of `aspellWithDicts` as a `buildInput`? - i.e. how do I build a self-contained aspell (with dictionaries) and then reference this in another derivation as a build input? Really appreciate your advise.

Comment: It should be as simple as `{aspellWithDicts, ...}: `...`buildInputs = [ aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en]) ];`, for example. It seems like something is wrong with the way you're using it in your dependent expression. It seems to me that your original question has been answered, so maybe you could accept the answer and open a new question with some details of what you're trying to achieve now?

Comment: Thanks Robert, that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `aspellWithDicts`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but since I found it I wanted to give what worked for me. I use Nix, I enjoy Nix, I promote Nix, but I don't really understand Nix. I take a more practical approach to it, here is an example setting up a dev environment with the english spell check dict.

```
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, ... }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        aspellWithDicts = pkgs.aspellWithDicts (d: [d.en]);
      in
      {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            aspellWithDicts
          ];
          shellHook = ''
            export PS1="nix:# ";
          '';
        };
      }
    );
  }
}
```

put this in flake.nix and you should be able to:

```
# aspell dump dicts
en
en-variant_0
en-variant_1
en-variant_2
en-w_accents
en-wo_accents
en_AU
en_AU-variant_0
en_AU-variant_1
en_AU-w_accents
en_AU-wo_accents
en_CA
en_CA-variant_0
en_CA-variant_1
en_CA-w_accents
en_CA-wo_accents
en_GB
en_GB-ise
en_GB-ise-w_accents
en_GB-ise-wo_accents
en_GB-ize
en_GB-ize-w_accents
en_GB-ize-wo_accents
en_GB-variant_0
en_GB-variant_1
en_GB-w_accents
en_GB-wo_accents
en_US
en_US-variant_0
en_US-variant_1
en_US-w_accents
en_US-wo_accents
```